# delphi CEF4 Chromium do not show web sites with secure connection error

Tags: delphi, chromium

I am created an application with CEF4 Chromium that browse pages in a local network. 
but my page has "Secure Connection Error" because of my url begin with "https". for example "https://10.36.159.212/login.html"
my program don't display anything at Chromiumwindow or CEFWindowParent.
it would be appriciate that help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, CEF cancels the request when a certificate issue occurs during its navigation. Hard to say what you want to do in your case, but in general, you should not work with content with some certificate issue. But if you know that it's safe for you, you can allow your request(s) to continue at least in these two ways:

### 1. Handle certificate issues for each request

You can write handler for the [**OnCertificateError**](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/(default)/CefRequestHandler.html#OnCertificateError(CefRefPtr%3CCefBrowser%3E,cef_errorcode_t,constCefString&,CefRefPtr%3CCefSSLInfo%3E,CefRefPtr%3CCefRequestCallback%3E)) event and handle each request certificate issue separately. With [**CEF4Delphi**](https://github.com/salvadordf/CEF4Delphi) library you can do it e.g. this way:

```
type
  TFormMain = class(TForm)
    ChromiumWindow1: TChromiumWindow;
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure ChromiumCertificateError(Sender: TObject; const browser: ICefBrowser;
      certError: TCefErrorcode; const requestUrl: ustring; const sslInfo: ICefSslInfo;
      const callback: ICefRequestCallback; out Result: Boolean);
  end;

procedure TFormMain.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ChromiumWindow1.ChromiumBrowser.OnCertificateError := ChromiumCertificateError;
  ChromiumWindow1.CreateBrowser;
end;

procedure TFormMain.ChromiumCertificateError(Sender: TObject; const browser: ICefBrowser;
  certError: TCefErrorcode; const requestUrl: ustring; const sslInfo: ICefSslInfo;
  const callback: ICefRequestCallback; out Result: Boolean);
begin
  Result := False;

  if MessageDlg(Format('Certificate error. Code: %d. Do you want to continue?',
    [Integer(certError)]), mtConfirmation, [mbYes, mbNo], 0) = mrYes then
  begin
    Result := True;
    callback.Cont(True);
  end;
end;
```

The principle of this event is simple. When you return **False** to the **Result** parameter, request that has reported a certificate issue will be immediately cancelled. When you return **True** to the **Result** parameter, request navigation will continue. But, except that you must say the request to continue (that's the call **callback.Cont(True)** in the above code), either in this event, or in some later one.

If you were interested about specific certificate errors, consult the **certError** parameter of the event with error code constants prefixed by **ERR_CERT_** defined in the [**uCEFConstants.pas**](https://github.com/salvadordf/CEF4Delphi/blob/master/source/uCEFConstants.pas#L84) module (for descriptions then see the [**net_error_list.h**](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/net/base/net_error_list.h) header file).

Another way of handling specific certificate errors would be getting status from the **sslInfo** interface and masking the status value by the **CERT_STATUS_** flags ([**uCEFConstants.pas**](https://github.com/salvadordf/CEF4Delphi/blob/master/source/uCEFConstants.pas#L115)).

### 2. Globally ignore all certificate issues

You can enable the [**ignore_certificate_errors**](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/(default)/_cef_settings_t.html#ignore_certificate_errors) option to globally ignore all certificate issues letting all the created CEF browsers navigate to the content despite all certificate issues (which is unsafe). For [**CEF4Delphi**](https://github.com/salvadordf/CEF4Delphi) library you can setup global settings typically in your project source, e.g. like this:

```
GlobalCEFApp := TCefApplication.Create;
try
  GlobalCEFApp.IgnoreCertificateErrors := True;

  if GlobalCEFApp.StartMainProcess then
  begin
    Application.Initialize;
    Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
    Application.CreateForm(TFormMain, FormMain);
    Application.Run;
  end;
finally
  GlobalCEFApp.Free;
end;
```

I would discourage from using this way as it may not be safe to navigate to content with certificate issue.